# squid ip based authentication

Tags: squid

I have 10 ip's on a VPS and squid3 installed. I want to lease all of them to 10 co-workers. The authentication should be ip-based.

Basically I want to allow only their home ip address (not internal - we're not on a network) to connect to my squid. I would also like to offer them a dedicated ip from my outgoing addresses. I managed to get it working using username/password based authentication but some software do not support that feature so I would like to switch to this limit if possible.

Any guidance/sample acl's?

Comment: Can we assume that the home IP's are statically assigned?

Comment: yes, all home ip's are static.

Answer (score 2):

Make an ACL like

```
acl coworkers 10.0.0.1
acl coworkers 10.0.0.2
```

to add single IPs to an ACL. For a network:

```
acl coworkers 10.0.0.0/8
```

then include an http_access line:

```
http_access allow coworkers
```

Comment: "Basically I want to allow only their home ip address (not internal - we're not on a network) to connect to my squid. I would also like to offer them a dedicated ip from my outgoing addresses."

Comment: Edited my sample acl to include networks.